# How powerful can graphing be in IE6?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, browser, internet-explorer-6, charts

I'm interested in developing a web-based application with rich time series charting functionality, where the charts can be constructed and manipulated on the client side. I would like the chart surface to be highly interactive, with the ability to pan and zoom with the mouse, click on lines, axes, etc. Importantly, I would prefer not to use Flash, AND I need to support Internet Explorer 6. My question is, is there anything out there that is going to allow me to do this, or must I use Flash? I have seen good charts that use the HTML5 canvas element, but I am not sure to what extent these would be supported in IE6 using excanvas.js, and if they are supported, what type of performance I can expect. I have not actually found a working example that ran in IE6.

Thanks.

Comment: IE 6 is on its way out... its 2 versions old... I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: creative IE: http://acid3.acidtests.org/

Comment: Use the HTML5 Canvas interactive graphs in modern browsers, and for IE6 you could just have an Ajax call to the server where a graph generator could reside, returning an image that replaces the previous image on the page. It would be less interactive, but technically IE6 would be supported.

Comment: Zoidberg: I agree with you that IE6 is on its way out; unfortunately, I'm targeting a corporate audience where most people are on locked down machines and where IE6 is still widely deployed.

Answer (score 2):

IE6 has VML support, VML is the *almost* equivalent of SVG Microsoft was pushing years ago.

Many frameworks today use VML to offer SVG and canvas functionalities.

**Raphael**, as already mentioned, is one.

**[Dojox.gfx](http://docs.dojocampus.org/dojox/gfx/)** (a dojo extension) is another one.
It offers canvas-like functionality, and now has an *SVG export function* in place.

**[AmpleSDK](http://www.amplesdk.com/)** is insanely awesome in *enabling SVG* (and more, even XUL) functionality everywhere feasible, *even on IE5.5*. (with some limitations)

Comment: Let's not forget [Cufon][http://cufon.shoqolate.com/generate/] and [typeface.js][http://typeface.neocracy.org/] that use VML and SVG to enable *sIFR* and *@font-face* like functionality on older browsers without flash. Even IE6.

Answer (score 1):

Remember IE has support for VML a rival to SVG, google use VML on maps when drawing road etc. I suspect they use xslt to translate their SVG output to VML.

http://www.lutanho.net/svgvml3d/index.html

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_Markup_Language

But I would recommend that you have a good look for a good existing cross browser library, that Highcharts mentioned by upper stage looks amazing - if you can compete with that fine, go for it...